# What is the default width and height of a group element in html (if it has any)?

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way to view the space occupied by group element inside a SVG element.

**SVG element's  width = 600 and Height = 500
g is translated to (100,100)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `getBBox` as shown in the snippet:

```js
const emptyBox = document.querySelector('.empty').getBBox();
console.log('EMPTY BOX: ', emptyBox);

const nonEmptyBox = document.querySelector('.non-empty').getBBox();
console.log('NON-EMPTY BOX: ', nonEmptyBox);
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="empty"/>
  <g class="non-empty">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```